# Can not connect Apache Cassandra with DataGrip

Tags: docker, cassandra, portainer

I try to deploy Apache Cassandra cluster with docker-compose in Portainer.

```
version: '2'
services:
  cassandra-node1:
    image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '9042:9042'
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cassandra-cluster
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-node1,cassandra-node2,cassandra-node3
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=pa$$word
      - CASSANDRA_TRANSPORT_PORT_NUMBER=7000

  cassandra-node2:
    image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cassandra-cluster
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-node1,cassandra-node2,cassandra-node3
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=pa$$word
      - CASSANDRA_TRANSPORT_PORT_NUMBER=7000

  cassandra-node3:
    image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=cassandra-cluster
      - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra-node1,cassandra-node2,cassandra-node3
      - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=pa$$word
      - CASSANDRA_TRANSPORT_PORT_NUMBER=7000
```

But when I try to connect, I get failed:

```
All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.0:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.0:9042] Cannot connect)).
```

But I can to connect from time to time.

And in Portainer I can see invalid password.

[Portainer GUI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE87W.png)

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your host network and port to this one. (listen_address)